# Error: Unknown error occurred when calling saveChanges. in JSDO

Tags: angular, typescript, openedge, progress-4gl

We are using Kendo + JSDO in our application. We are getting an error when we try to delete a record like so:

```
this.datasource.saveChanges()
   .subscribe((response: DataResult) => {

   }, (error, response) => {
       //this.dataSource.eTTtemp.getErrors();
   });
```

And this is the error:

```
core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unknown error occurred when calling saveChanges.
Error: Unknown error occurred when calling saveChanges.
    at DataSource.push../node_modules/@progress/jsdo-angular/lib/progress.data.angular.js.DataSource.normalizedErrorObj (progress.data.angular.js:656)
    at progress.data.angular.js:519
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at zone.js:724
    at progress.data.angular.js:518
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:387)
    at Zone../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
    at zone.js:872
    at ZoneDelegate../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
```

However, when we call `getErrors()`, we get a blank  return for a particular scenario while other situations do return the errors with `getErrors()`. Moreover the `error` variable returns the above error message perfectly fine in when `getErrors()` returns nothing.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking for help with. Are you asking when you should use `error` vs `getErrors()`, are you trying to find out why `getErrors()` doesn't contain the same information as `error`, something else entirely?

Comment: I am performing a remove and savechanges. After the network call completes, since errors are returned , it goes to error block. In a particular scenario, getErrors() return blank but in other cases it returns proper messages.

Comment: So is your question just "why does `getErrors()` not always have the errors?"